# Elasticsearch - sort multi-index query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm building an autocomplete search with elasticsearch so I need to query 3 indexes `posts`, `comments`, `authors`. I have the following query:

```
{
   "query":{
      "query_string":{
         "query":"something"
      }
   }
}
```

the call:

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/posts,comments,authors/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "something"
    }
  }
}'
```

I need to sort the results by specific index fields, for example:

posts index has a field called `comments_count`, comments `votes_count` and authors `posts_count`. When comparing posts, then it should sort by `comments_count`, when comments then `votes_count`, when authors then `posts_count`.

It's possible to do something like that? I wouldn't like to merge the indexes into one because they indexes completely different documents.

Answer (score 3):

Well, my problem was that if i sort by a field that is not present in all indexes, documents wont be returned.

Managed to solve with:

```
{
   "_script":{
      "script":"type=doc['_type'].value;if(type=='posts'){return doc['comments_count'].value} else {return 0};",
      "type":"number",
      "order":"desc"
   }
}
```

at least now the documents are shown, even if at the bottom.

Comment: "if i sort by a field that is not present in all indexes, documents wont be returned." That is controllable. See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/sort/. In your case you should probably use `{"missing" : "_last"}`

Comment: @Geert-Jan thanks for pointing in the right direction! Using scripts for this is way too complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `comments_count`, `votes_count` and `posts_count` you could put into index the same name (e.g. `items_count`) and perform usual sort:

```
{
  "sort": [
    { "items_count": "desc" }
  ]
}
```

If there are other entities which lack `items_count` there is an option to [ignore unmapped fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_ignoring_unmapped_fields):

```
{
  "sort": [
    { "items_count": { "order": "desc", "unmapped_type": "long" } }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html

Use ignore unmapped_type to ignore the field when querying against multiple indexes and the field does not exist in other indexes.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.